# Delete/Edit album group in ALAssetsLibrary, is it possible?

Tags: ios, xcode, photos, alassetslibrary

If an app creates a group in ALAssetsLibrary via "addAssetsGroupAlbumWithName:", is there a way to delete it again from within that app or change its name ?

cheers

Comment: I don't think you could do that within the app.

Answer (score 1):

There is no **Delete** option available now.